# Unable to create groups using test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-group, facebook-test-users

I have an app with 4 test users which are all in each others' friend lists. I need to create a group with all of them. I clicked "Create a group" and I am asked for the name of the group and some members. When I type the name of the members, there is no suggestion list. Even though I type the exact name of the other test users, I get an error saying that I need to choose some friends to join the group. Anyone knows how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into the same issue right now and don't have a great solution.

However, for most purposes, a group is just a proxy user who can share information with a set of members. So, for my app, I'm just going to proceed by creating a user named "Test Group" and have my users friend that user to join the group.

For my purposes, that should give me everything I need without requiring me to spend much more time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As a test user, you need to add some friends, at least one. But you can not be friends with real people. 
So I created 2 test users, logged with them into 2 browsers, sent frined request from one to the other, and after accepting that, I was able to create group as a test user, adding this my other test user as a friend here.

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was unable to create a group using the quick access in the [navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScDtU.png) which the modal closes itself automatically.

The issue is resolved when I navigated to [my Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ9jZ.png) > then create a group from there.

Answer (score -1):

This may seem like an obvious question, but have you signed in as one of the test users to create your group?

1. Go to your test users and select 'Edit' for one of them. Sign in as
   the test user.
2. Create a group with the test user.
3. Add your test user's friends to the group.